# Cannot reach MySQL server on CentOS from Workbench

Tags: mysql, ssh, centos, mysql-workbench, putty

I installed my CentOS MySQL server on my remote server, I created a new user profile and modified my.cnf. But I can not reach the DB from the MySQL Workbench client installed on Windows. Using Git Bash on Windows I can reach the server correctly and I can also authenticate. Some advice?

Following is the content of my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Your question as it stands needs editing to be in English, please, in line with [stackoverflow's English-only policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/).

Comment: Marco, Per favore traduci la tua domanda in inglese.

Comment: Translated and cleaned it up

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Rico it seems policy is not to translate posts on behalf of the user: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/13317

Comment: @Kenster thanks for the pointer. I'll vote to close this.